# Assign names to vector entries without assigning the vector a variable name?

Tags: r, variables, variable-assignment

In R, is it possible to assign names to components of a vector without first assigning that vector to a variable name?
The normal way is obviously:

```
z <- 1:3
names(z) <- c("a", "b", "c") #normal way
names(1:3) <- c("a", "b", "c") #throws an error
```

The second way throws "Error in names(1:3) <- c("a", "b", "c") : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object"

According to the doc, the expression is evaluated as

```
 z <- "names<-"(z,
     "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))’.
```

So no shock it doesn't work, I'm just wondering if there's a work around.

Ideally, it'd be nice to have something like:

```
names(z <- 1:3) <- c("a", "b", "c")
> z
a b c 
1 2 3
```

Just seems like a waste of space to put that on two different lines.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

How about using `setNames()`, which seems even cleaner/clearer than your suggested ideal?

```
z <- setNames(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"))
# z
# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```

Comment: just checked, apparently set names is just a function wrapper for the 'normal way'. Still a space saver, but its not doing anything fancy.

Comment: @zzk -- Yeah, I saw that too (and also noticed that it's in the **stats** package, oddly enough). Clearly someone else tired of not having it available in base R, and wrote it up as a little convenience function.

Answer (score 4):

Always thought this was a little cleaner, also don't need an additional package:

```
z <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3)
# z
# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```